# Sort JSON data by date javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sorting

I am trying to sort my **json data** by **date** but its not working. here is what I am trying. please correct me where I am making mistake

**Sample Code**

```
var temp = [{
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "abc",
    "start": "2016-03-23 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}, {
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "def",
    "start": "2016-04-13 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}, {
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "ghi",
    "start": "2016-04-08 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}];

console.log(temp);

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    if (new Date(a.start) == new Date(b.start)) {
        return a.row == b.row ? 0 : +a.row > +b.row ? 1 : -1;
    }

    return new Date(a.start) > (b.start) ? 1 : -1;
});

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: This is not JSON! It's a Javascript array with objects in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the date string for sorting, while it is an [ISO 6801](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date.

```js
var temp = [{ "id": 17608, "title": "abc", "start": "2016-03-23 06:13:00.0", "backgroundColor": "#000000", "borderColor": "#000000", "textColor": "#fff" }, { "id": 17608, "title": "def", "start": "2016-04-13 06:13:00.0", "backgroundColor": "#000000", "borderColor": "#000000", "textColor": "#fff" }, { "id": 17608, "title": "ghi", "start": "2016-04-08 06:13:00.0", "backgroundColor": "#000000", "borderColor": "#000000", "textColor": "#fff" }];

temp.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.start.localeCompare(b.start);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(temp, 0, 4) + "</pre>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `date.getTime()` while comparing dates.

```js
var temp= [{id:17608,title:"abc",start:"2016-03-23 06:13:00.0",backgroundColor:"#000000",borderColor:"#000000",textColor:"#fff"},{id:17608,title:"def",start:"2016-04-13 06:13:00.0",backgroundColor:"#000000",borderColor:"#000000",textColor:"#fff"},{id:17608,title:"ghi",start:"2016-04-08 06:13:00.0",backgroundColor:"#000000",borderColor:"#000000",textColor:"#fff"}];

console.log(temp);

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
  var d1 = new Date(a.start).getTime();
  var d2 = new Date(b.start).getTime();
  return d1<d2?-1:d1>d2?1:0;
});

console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine, it's just that you're missing the second `new Date()` in your comparison:

```
return new Date(a.start) > (b.start) ? 1 : -1;
```

Should be:

```
return new Date(a.start) > new Date(b.start) ? 1 : -1;
```

The way it is now, you're simply comparing a `Date` object to `string`.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of achieving this. Of them, the easiest would be to convert the strings to dates and substract them from each other to get a negative, positive or zero number:

```
temp.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a.start) - new Date(b.start);
});
```

It is often believed that the sort function needs to return `-1`, `1` or `0`. This is simply not true. It will sort the items based on if the number is *positive*, *negative* or *zero*. The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.sort) states it as:

> If comparefn is not undefined, it should be a function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a negative value if x < y, zero if x = y, or a positive value if x > y.

Full example:

```
var temp = [{
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "abc",
    "start": "2016-03-23 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}, {
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "def",
    "start": "2016-04-13 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}, {
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "ghi",
    "start": "2016-04-08 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}];

console.log(temp);

temp.sort(function(a,b){
  // Convert strings to dates and substract.
  // This way you get a value which is negative, positive or zero
  return new Date(a.start) - new Date(b.start);
});

console.log(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const groups = this.posts.reduce((groups, data) => {
    const date = data.published_date.split(' ')[0];
    if (!groups[date]) {
      groups[date] = [];
    }
    groups[date].push(data);
    return groups;
  }, {});

  // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
  const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
    return {
      date,
      posts: groups[date]
    };
  });
```

do this, it should work!

Answer (score 0):

```
        var temp = [{
        "id": 17608,
        "title": "abc",
        "start": "2016-03-23 06:13:00.0",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000",
        "borderColor": "#000000",
        "textColor": "#fff"
    }, {
        "id": 17608,
        "title": "def",
        "start": "2016-04-13 06:13:00.0",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000",
        "borderColor": "#000000",
        "textColor": "#fff"
    }, {
        "id": 17608,
        "title": "ghi",
        "start": "2016-04-08 06:13:00.0",
        "backgroundColor": "#000000",
        "borderColor": "#000000",
        "textColor": "#fff"
    }];
    
    
    
    const groups = this.temp.reduce((groups, data) => {
        const date = data.start.split(' ')[0];
        if (!groups[date]) {
          groups[date] = [];
        }
        groups[date].push(data);
        return groups;
      }, {});
    
      // Edit: to add it in the array format instead
      const groupArrays = Object.keys(groups).map((date) => {
        return {
          date,
          temps: groups[date]
        };
      });

console.log(groupArrays)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var temp = [{
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "abc",
    "start": "2016-03-23 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}, {
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "def",
    "start": "2016-04-13 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}, {
    "id": 17608,
    "title": "ghi",
    "start": "2016-04-08 06:13:00.0",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "textColor": "#fff"
}];

console.log(temp);

temp.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a.start) - parseFloat(b.start);
});

console.log(temp);
```

Comment: that would sort only by year.